# How to read version data in Salesforce

Tags: contentversion, python

From Salesforce File, I want read the file and get the content between some text and store it in the Custom object record field. For this i have created external API(python script deployed to heroku) where i am sending the file content as blob(basically the content of the file is Blob in Salesforce ) . Now i want read the file and get the text . But I was not able read the blob data. If i convert the blob to string in SF while posting and decode it in python also doesn't work .
Can we send file.
Please give some inputs on this .

my python code :

```python
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    import base64
    import blob
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/get/record/', methods=['GET', 'POST','DELETE', 'PATCH'])
    def index():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("===inside===")
            payload_list = request.get_json(force=True)           
            print("====next line payload_list ===")
            print(blob(payload_list["BlobData"])
            # responseStr = str(payload_list["BlobData"])
            # print("===decodedata===")
            # print(base64.b64decode(responseStr))
      return "sucesss"
```

Salesforce Rest Code

```apex
    List<ContentVersion> cv = [SELECT ContentDocumentId,VersionData from ContentVersion
                               where ContentDocumentId = 'xxxxxxxxxx' order by CreatedDate DESC];
    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cv[0].versiondata);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://realpyth.herokuapp.com/get/fileService/');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setBody('{"BlobData":"'+cv[0].versiondata+'"}'); // Send the data as Blob
    //request.setBody('{"BlobData":"'+bodyEncoded+'"}'); // Convert the blob data and send as String
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('=======' +response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getBody());
    } else {
    System.debug('====response==='+response.getBody());
    }
```

Comment: This approach is inherently limited by the Apex heap limit, preventing you from sending large files. Consider instead calling your Flask server with the Id of the relevant version(s) and having Python call the REST API to _pull_ the actual blob data.

Comment: @David Reed I have tried the REST API directly to get the version data. But I am tried with this url I am getting below error. URL :services/data/v52.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/xxxxxxxxxx/VersionData     reponse would be {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}

Answer (score 0):

The problem's with the server code, I believe. Given your current Apex, you should:

```
import base64
```

...

```
print(base64.standard_b64decode(payload_list["BlobData"]))
```

Or:

```
from base64 import standard_b64decode
```

...

```
print(standard_b64decode(payload_list["BlobData"]))
```

Comment: I have tried but still the output coming as blob like "taskpanes.xml.relsPK\x01\x02-\x00\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xe4\xfd\xa03<\x04\x00\x009\x0c\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x17\x00\x00word/settings.xmlPK\0\x00"